# Automatically exit the program when it crashes?

Tags: c#, windows-7, crash

Is there any way to make a program stop and exit the program when it crashes? I am using C# to develop the program and machines it is run on are 32 bit Windows 7 Professional machines.

So, for example, when my X.exe crashes, a little pop-up window with 2 options come up: 
1 - Look for solutions online.
2 - Stop X.exe

I want the second option to be automatically selected and my program is stopped. I have another program that monitors X.exe so when X.exe is stopped, it will start a new instance of X.exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a global exception handler for unhandled exceptions. This handler is always called when your program did not handle an exception during runtime which will cause the programm to crash:

In Wpf-Applications you can add the handler like this:

```
App.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler( Current_DispatcherUnhandledException );
```

The same for WinForms:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler( OnThreadException );
```

And for console applications:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler( OnUnhandledException );
```

Answer (score 2):

This code should guide you the way:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    // catch app errors
    Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    try
    {
        Application.Run(new Form());
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        // show popupform
        PopupForm popup = new PopupForm();
        if(popup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}

static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // show popupform
    PopupForm popup = new PopupForm();
    if(popup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Lg warappa